# Docker complaining about ALL_PROXY environment variable with "proxy: unknown scheme: http"

Tags: go, docker, proxy

I'm facing the following issue with my Docker containers: When I try to *enter* the container using

```
docker exec -it container-id /bin/bash
```

Docker (I assume it's Docker) complains with the following message:

```
proxy: unknown scheme: http
```

I have traced this back to the following environment variable that's set on my host machine, since I'm using a proxy server to access the web:

```
ALL_PROXY=http://myproxy:8080
```

The error message seems to come from the `net/proxy.go` file, which can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/proxy/proxy.go) - the error message is issued on the last line of the file. Why would `http` not be a registered URL scheme in the Docker case?

As soon as I `unset ALL_PROXY` on the host, I can enter the container without any issues.

Environment:

- Mac OS X v10.11.5
- Docker v1.11.1
- Docker-Machine v0.7.0

Any idea how to fix this (other than unsetting the variable each time)?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue with docker 1.11.2.  I believe the error is coming from method [FromURL](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/vendor/src/golang.org/x/net/proxy/proxy.go#L93).

After checking the relevant commit https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/16effc66c028a7800096ed92174ca4bceba229ad, it turns out from v1.11.0-rc1 up to v1.12.0-rc4 are including this commit.

So the solution for me is to install a lower version (I used v1.10.3) of docker toolbox, after which "docker run hello-world" works.