# invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http : VSCode Cloud Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, skaffold, google-cloud-code

I tried to follow the instructions on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtMIEtLQNa0
to run a Cloud Run service locally.
I created a sample Python hello-world application. When I choose the option "Run On Cloud Run Emulator", it gives me an error saying "invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http".

Any pointers on how this can be solved?
I'm using an Intel Mac, on a corporate VPN.

```
Skaffold &{Version:v2.0.4 ConfigVersion:skaffold/v4beta1 GitVersion: GitCommit: ....BuildDate:2022-12-21T09:11:50Z GoVersion:go1.19.1 Compiler:gc Platform:darwin/amd64 User:}
Loaded Skaffold defaults from \"/Users/.../.skaffold/config\"
map entry found when executing locate for &{hello-world-2 . 0x.... {<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0x.... <nil>} [] {[] []} []} of type *latest.Artifact and pointer: 824635590528
Using kubectl context: cloud-run-dev-internal
invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http
Skaffold exited with code 1.
invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http
Deleted the temporary directory /var/folders/4j/../T/cloud-code-cloud-run-JSw6y6.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what version of docker you are running?  I believe this issue is related to the version of docker being used and/or the current proxy settings setup for docker.  Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573476/docker-complaining-about-all-proxy-environment-variable-with-proxy-unknown-sch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I followed the getting started guide (using skaffold v2.10.0), i.e.:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold
cd skaffold/examples/buildpacks-node-tutorial
skaffold init
minikube start --profile custom
skaffold config set --global local-cluster true
eval $(minikube -p custom docker-env)
```

Once I call `skaffold dev` I get:

> invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http

I am behind a corporate proxy.

If I do

```bash
unset ALL_PROXY
unset all_proxy
```

before the skaffold command the issue is gone.

Would be nice if skaffold (or its transitive dependencies) would be less pedantic here.