# Basic skaffold run giving proxy error to run a Flask hello world

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I'm new to Kubernetes and Skaffold. Tried to follow the blog article to run a Python Flask application using Skaffold.

https://mukherjee-aniket.medium.com/continuous-development-using-skaffold-with-local-kubernetes-cluster-with-hot-reload-61009e185258

But when I run the command `skaffold dev --port-forward` I get the below error message.

```
invalid skaffold config: proxy: unknown scheme: http
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Clone https://github.com/anikm1987/skaffold-kubernetes/tree/master/python_app_k8s
2. cd python_app_k8s
3. skaffold init
4. skaffold dev --port-forward

Comment: Hi Ashok are you sure you are using **skaffold init**. Because in steps reproduce you kept **scaffold** with c not k  that is the wrong spell right?

Comment: HI @DharaniDharGolladasari sorry it was a typo while typing. Corrected the steps.

Comment: Can you clarify what version of docker you are running?  I believe this issue is related to the version of docker being used and/or the current proxy settings setup for docker.  Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573476/docker-complaining-about-all-proxy-environment-variable-with-proxy-unknown-sch

Comment: The being thrown is from Skaffold's schema validation checks:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/main/cmd/skaffold/app/cmd/runner.go#L87-L89

It seems this is most likely coming from validateDockerNetworkMode:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/main/pkg/skaffold/schema/validation/validation.go#L390-L411

Comment: One possible workaround (assuming it is feasible to not use a proxy) would be try running `unset ALL_PROXY` and see if this error still occurs when you attempt this (workaround is mentioned in the above linked stackoverflow question)